# Abbreviated title in \footcite, full title in \printbibligraphy

Tags: biblatex

Using biblatex with:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=authortitle,backref=true,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
```

Generating footnote citations with `\footcite` and the bibliography with `\printbibliography`.

I'm citing a lot of EU directives and regulations and the titles are very long.  When I have several of them on a page the footnotes end up taking up a third or more of the page.

Is there any way to have an abbreviated title that I specify appear in the footnotes but the full title appear in the bibliography?

Comment: You can temporarly move the shorttitle field to the title field `\AtEveryCitekey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, using the shorttitle field with the following in the preamble (a few extra bits for things I wanted to do):

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearfield{urlyear}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{\iffieldundef{shorttitle}{labeltitle}{shorttitle}}
  \iffieldundef{date}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}{}{\nametitledelim\printfield{year}}}{\nametitledelim\printfield{date}}%
  \iffieldundef{note}{%
  }{\nametitledelim\printfield{note}}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}{%
  }{\nametitledelim\printfield{pages}}}}
```